# Prove that for a connected $(m,n)$ plane graph $G$ in which every face is bounded by an $l$-cycle $m = \frac{l(n-2)}{l-2}$.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for a connected $(m,n)$ plane graph $G$ in which every face is bounded by an $l$-cycle $m = \frac{l(n-2)}{l-2}$.

I think I am misunderstanding this question. As an example I take a graph that is two conjoined squares such as this: [image: Graph].

This graph has $n = 6$ vertices and $m = 7$ edges, and both faces are bounded by $4$-cycles.

But then the formula gives $ 7 = \frac{4 \times (6-2)}{4-2} = \frac{16}{2} = 8$.

I assume that I am not fully understanding the kind of graph that the problem is talking about?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Every face including the outer face.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that every face is bounded by an $l-$cycle means that every face has $l$ sides. This implies that the sum of the sides of every face is equal to $lf$ (where $f$ is the number of the faces of the graph). On the other hand, this sum is equal to $2m$, since each edge, which is a side of a face, is counted twice in this sum. So $2m=lf$. Using Euler's formula, $n-m+f=2$, we get the desired result.

In your example the outer face is bounded by a cycle of length 6, whereas the inner faces are bounded by cycles of length 4.